# How do i verify a file format?

Tags: file-format

[Basically this question except i am using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759855/verifying-uploaded-file). How do i take a given file and check if it is

- image (all formats except bitmap including photoshop)
- archive (7z, rar, zip, etc). NOTE: I know a file can be both an image and zip. I can check if its both in code.
- sound (most such as m4a, flac, ogg, but not wav)
- model (3ds, X, B3D, etc)

The solution does not need to check all of these but if i can get a few to check all of these then great.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/

Comment: Substring on given filename to get the filetype?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to either:

- Find documentation for the file format and check for known bytes in the file header, etc
- Attempt to load the file using an API - if the file loads successfully then you know it is of the proper type.

For example, here is an example of how to verify an image file: [validate-image-from-file-in-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c)

Of course, the mime type and/or file extension can give you a good guess of what file format you are dealing with, but (depending on the source) you should not rely on it exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Given the variety of your file types, checking the extension may be the best option. Anyone has other thoughts?

Comment: This is a good first step, but you really should do a more thorough examination, especially if files will be uploaded by anyone on the Internet...

Comment: yes, I totally agree. The uploaded file may be virus or some dry-by-downloads. What I did was that I always rename the file with my desired extensions in order to prevent auto-run. But this is nothing close to detecting the file type though.